# JSON.Net references become null

Tags: serialization, json.net

I'm serializing my game state with JSON.Net, but weirdly some references are becoming null. They seem to serialize fine (the $id and $ref seem to be properly set when checking the output json), but the deserialized objectes contain null references where they shouldn't.

My state is as follows: I have a planet, which contains a list of tiles. Each tile knows it neighbours (again a list of tiles).

Here's a little piece of the json, the initial serialization: (most important part is the last line, where neighbours has uses a ref number)

```
"Tiles": {
  "$id": "3",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "$type": "WarSystems.Tile, Assembly-CSharp",
      "_type": 0,
      "ID": "161d8ca1-f086-49eb-94ba-0b5b3bbb0921",
      "Position": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": -1.71737635
      },
      "Normal": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": -1.0
      },
      "Neighbours": [
        {
          "$id": "5",
          "$type": "WarSystems.Tile, Assembly-CSharp",
          "_type": 2,
          "ID": "f34a2bb1-4a10-49db-b2d5-7980ccc55760",
          "Position": {
            "x": 0.2789981,
            "y": -0.8586796,
            "z": -1.460893
          },
          "Normal": {
            "x": 0.1624527,
            "y": -0.4999933,
            "z": -0.850656152
          },
          "Neighbours": [
            {
              "$ref": "4"
            },
```

"Tiles" is the list of tiles in the planet. As you can see, the first tile has a neighbour, and their neighbour has the first tile as his neighbour. Serializing goes fine, all there neighbours are set properly.

However, when I deserialize this, and then reserialize that, I get the following: (now notice that neighbours has a null)

```
"Tiles": {
  "$id": "3",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "$type": "WarSystems.Tile, Assembly-CSharp",
      "_type": 0,
      "ID": "161d8ca1-f086-49eb-94ba-0b5b3bbb0921",
      "Position": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": -1.71737635
      },
      "Normal": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": -1.0
      },
      "Neighbours": [
        {
          "$id": "5",
          "$type": "WarSystems.Tile, Assembly-CSharp",
          "_type": 2,
          "ID": "f34a2bb1-4a10-49db-b2d5-7980ccc55760",
          "Position": {
            "x": 0.2789981,
            "y": -0.8586796,
            "z": -1.460893
          },
          "Normal": {
            "x": 0.1624527,
            "y": -0.4999933,
            "z": -0.850656152
          },
          "Neighbours": [
            null,
```

As you can see, the first neighbour is now null. (I also checked the actual deserialized object, it also has the null reference, so it seems the deserializing goes wrong. Of course there is a lot more, but this part shows what's going wrong and the whole json would be a bit much to post.)

Lastly, this is how I (de)serialize:

```
private static string SerializeState(State state)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state, SerializerSettings);
}


private static State DeserializeState(string serialized)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<State>(serialized, SerializerSettings);
}
```

With the SerializerSettings shared between them:

```
private static JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { new Vector3Converter() },
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
```

(Vector3Converter is used to serialize Unity's Vector3. It simply serializes it as an object with 3 field: x, y, and z. As the `Position` property in the tiles.)

Does anyone know what's going wrong, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Edit, the Planet and Tile class:

```
public class Planet
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }

    public List<Tile> Tiles { get; set; }

    public Planet(Vector3 pos, List<Tile> tiles)
    {
        Position = pos;
        Tiles = tiles;
    }
}

public class Tile
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [JsonRequired]
    private TileType _type;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public TileType Type 
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            if (_type != value)
            {
                _type = value;
                if (TypeChanged != null) TypeChanged(_type);
            }
        }
    }

    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Normal { get; set; }

    private List<Tile> _neighbours = new List<Tile>(6); //6 since we use a hex grid
    public List<Tile> Neighbours { get { return _neighbours; } set { _neighbours = value; } }

    // Events
    public event System.Action<TileType> TypeChanged;

    public Tile(TileType type, Vector3 pos, Vector3 normal)
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        Position = pos;
        Normal = normal;
    }

    public void AddNeighbour(Tile neighbour)
    {
        _neighbours.Add(neighbour);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough information for us to help - is there any chance of creating an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  What does that `Neighbours` collection look like?  It is just a `List<Neighbour>` or does it validate added and removed items somehow?

Comment: Yes, the neighbours is just a list:`private List<Tile> _neighbours = new List<Tile>(6);` `public List<Tile> Neighbours { get { return _neighbours; } set { _neighbours = value; } }`. I've added the planet and tile class.

Comment: I've made a mcve here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y9PSbZ The commented code is everything. If I also comment out the TileType enum (and comment out wherever it is used, as constructor param and the event) it does deserialize properly.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. When I added an empty constructor for Tile it worked. Why is that needed? And why doesn't JSON.Net give an error when the constructor is missing?

Comment: When there is no parameterless constructor but there is one single constructor with parameters, Json.NET will use that, matching the constructor argument names to JSON object property names.  Maybe that doesn't work properly with `PreserveReferencesHandling.All` for collections?

Comment: Ah, weird. Could be PreserveReferencesHandling, but then not only for All, since I tried all others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it. Once I added an empty constructor in my `Tile` class everything works as intended.

```
public Tile() { } //for deserialization
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  You could make it private and mark it with [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm).